# Failed to run test with Detox and Expo

Tags: react-native, automated-tests, detox

I updated package.json but the error says they cannot find configuration name. What I did is following [blog post by expo](https://blog.expo.dev/testing-expo-apps-with-detox-and-react-native-testing-library-7fbdbb82ac87) and created project from scratch with expo then got error after execute `detox test ----configuration ios.sim`. I did not updated `.detoxrc.json` but `package.json`. According to [Official Docs](https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/Introduction.GettingStarted.md#apply-detox-configuration), Detox scan `.detoxrc.json` and `package.json` both. Did I miss something?

The error said

```
 Failed to find a configuration named "ios.sim" in Detox config at path:
/Users/<user name>/Workspace/my-pj/detox-test-expo/.detoxrc.json
```

But I added to package.json like this

```
"detox": {
"test-runner": "jest",
"configurations": {
  "ios.sim": {
    "binaryPath": "bin/Exponent.app",
    "type": "ios.simulator",
    "name": "iPhone 12"
  }
}
```

},